# Expand SVG shape height to match content

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created an SVG shape which will contain various text based content, ranging between 1 - 8 lines. I've created my shape and content, but I'm using a `position:absolute;` rule to pull the content into the SVG. Which means if I add more content the shape won't expand.

Is this possible using an SVG element, I'm looked at using the `text` tag but it seems that the text is broken into single lines, and drawn at a specific x,y which I don't believe will work in my case.

```
    <div class="wrp">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1416 200">
    <path d="M1337.59107,-1.0658141e-14 L0,-1.0658141e-14 L0,325 L1027.36348,325 L1337.59107,-3.90798505e-14 Z" id="Combined-Shape" stroke="none" fill="#9DC8F2" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
<div class="img-wrp">
  <img src="https://www.maxizoo.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/aliments-hamster.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="caption-wrp">
        <div class="item">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sodales, odio ut egestas egestas, orci neque interdum sem, at malesuada enim tellus eget dui.
          </p>
          <span>Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm pulling the content;

```
.caption-wrp{
  padding:0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
}
```

JSFiddle -
https://jsfiddle.net/783ob55u/2/

Everything I read about SVG (view box) suggests its drawn to a fix size.

Edit - Example of what I'm trying to achieve (not the content size will change) - 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use the SVG as background-image in your text container?

Comment: Some idea of what this is supposed to look like would be useful. What's the purpose of the hamster image.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted another solution for you, if I understand well it should be a good base to get what you want.
The image is not perfectly fitted for that purpose so you may want to either find another one or have a set of 2 images to toggle with media queries.

Have a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWyeQN

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 1.5em 20% 1.5em 1em;
  background-color: #69f;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right-corner {
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7XbUc4oQQ0d0Ig4DvKipwx81Jk2B6FTsD7iyZCMS6tHBhHEQ7) no-repeat right top;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
polygon {
  fill:#69f;
}
```

The whole wrapper is responsive and the text block also and the right border will always cover 100% height of the container.

Let me know if something is not very clear.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Thats brilliant I just have one question I've moved your answer to a fiddle. Could you tell me why when using a bootstrap grid system the image and triangle overlaps the content rather than pushing it away.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4osu39f/1/

Comment: @SamXronn, my pleasure. for the overlaping on bootstrap, i would need to see the piece of code that you use, can you update your js fiddle? btw, why did you copy my trial to jsfiddle? is it the pug that disturbed you? :)

Comment: Yes the pug thing did scare me, and I wanted to include an external library ;). The fiddle post above does show all of my code, however if you resize your browser or scale that output window you'll see the image on the right at some points overlaps the content. Thanks

Comment: I have updated your fiddle,even if I did not see any problem on chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/n4osu39f/4/. Let me know if it is fixed. (About codepen you can add bootstrap too in settings > css > quick add. and view compiled html from pug in HTML pane arrow icon)

Comment: Aha I'll bare that in mind when using codepen, I'll use that feature next time! Thanks for your updated fiddle, the container on the outside of the `.box` now stops that content block being full width. Is it still possible to have the background and image full width with the content inside the container?

Comment: I understand your problem. Well I recommend to leave that piece of wrapper as is and apply bootstrap grid system only inside and outside if you need. The reason is that the absolute positioning and percentage margins (20% - that you can customize) are conflicting with bootstrap grid own margins and floating system. So converting all to bootsrap would make this snippet more complex as the 100% height would be harder to apply on the svg.

Comment: I have created a new fiddle anyway with the bootstrap way, but it is less natural! http://jsfiddle.net/n4osu39f/5/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should position you images as `position: absolute;` and let the text to take it's actual height. Look at this example that I made for you.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h62m5jow/1/)